# Getting error "object not found"

Tags: r, function

below is the function I am trying to create:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
    directory <- "specdata"      
    pollutant <- c("sulfate", "nitrate")
    na.rm = TRUE
    pollutmean <- sum/every
    pollutmean


  for(i in seq_along(id)) {
    read.csv(id.csv)
      for(j in seq_len(ncol(pollutant))) {
        every <- every + 1
        sum <- sum + pollutant(j, )
      }
    }
}
```

When I run the following code, I get the following error message:

```
source("pollutantmean.R")
pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
## Error in pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10) : 
##  object 'every' not found
```

I am trying to create a variable `every` to enumerate every time the `for()` loop goes through a cycle, but the error message tells me the object `every` is not found.
I don't know what I am doing incorrectly and I don't understand why I don't get the same type of error for `sum` and for `pollutmean`.

Comment: Umm... you didn't initialize the variable `every` inside your function...

Comment: You only get the first error. There is no effort to "compile" a list of all errors.

Comment: the read.csv line is actually doing...nothing.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment, you need to initialize your variable, `every`, either inside or outside of your function before calling it.

Also, you don't get an error for `sum` because `sum` is a function in R. If `every` was defined, you *would* get an error because you cannot treat a function that way. You can overload `sum` with a different value, but since you don't define `sum` as a different variable, it will assume that it is the function, `sum`.

Also, `pollutant(j, )` won't work - I think you want `pollutant[j, ]`.